# Ensuring table contains only unique values for certain fields

Tags: mysql, import, duplicates

I have a MYSQL table defined thusly:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Unique_Hash BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
   Size BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
   DateAdded DATETIME NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID),
   INDEX (Unique_Hash)
);
```

I expect to populate this table with 1,000's of records but the Unique_Hash/Size pair should never be added in another record. Instead I want to ensure that if any new record matching my existing Unique_Hash/Size values gets ignored. It's the DateAdded field which breaks my ON DUPLICATE IGNORE parameter.

How can I safely import data into this table ensuring that my records are unique relative to my Unique_Hash and Size fields?

Answer (score 0):

Create a multi-column unique index on Unique_Hash and Size fields. This will definitely prevent any entries with the same data to be inserted into the table.

While importing the data you can use `insert ignore ...` statements to ignore any errors received during the insertion due to unique index conflict. Those will be reported as warnings instead.

Just be aware of the side effects of using [ignore option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html):

> Data conversions that would trigger errors abort the statement if
>   IGNORE is not specified. With IGNORE, invalid values are adjusted to
>   the closest values and inserted; warnings are produced but the
>   statement does not abort. You can determine with the mysql_info() C
>   API function how many rows were actually inserted into the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an Index on your table that ensure the unicity condition of yout two columns :

```
ALTER TABLE `Data` ADD UNIQUE `Unicity` (`Unique_Hash`, `Size `);
```

With this instruction your pair will be unique accross the table (no duplicate pairs can be inserted). If you try to insert a duplicate pair you will get this error :

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry 'XXX-XXXX' for key 'Unicity'
```

Another solution could be to eliminate duplicate pairs before making the insert.
To do so you can work for instance with http://openrefine.org/
Formerly Google Refine. I worked with it once for this type of task and I had some pretty good results.

I hop it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I did which seems to have solved my problem:

I (re)defined my table as:

CREATE TABLE Data (
   ID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   Unique_Hash BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
   Size BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
   DateAdded *s/DATETIME/TIMESTAMP/* **DEFAULT** *s/NOT NULL/CURRENT_TIMESTAMP/*,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID),
   *s/INDEX/UNIQUE KEY/* (Unique_Hash)
);

Now I can import data such as:

> INSERT IGNORE INTO Data (Unique_Hash, Size) SELECT Hash AS Unique_Hash, Size FROM Temp;

This now adds the CURRENT_TIME field automatically as well as prevents dupes from my Temp table being imported.

Comment: No, this will not only prevent duplicates being added as per your definition in the question, since you only defined unique_hash field as unique index, while in the question you described the combination of unique_hash and size as the requirement for uniqueness. Your answer is at odds with your own question.